# Get Foreign Key Value

Tags: django, foreign-keys

How can I get the foreign key values?  I have a common vehicle model that links to the year, series, engine type, body style, transmission and drive train...all as foreign keys.  I'd like to get the values of these fields for my app, but I'm stuck as to how I'd go about them.  Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

```
class Model(models.Model):

  model = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
  manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
  date_added = models.DateField()
  def __unicode__(self):
      name = ''+str(self.manufacturer)+" "+str(self.model)
      return name 


class Year(models.Model):

  ALPHA_NUMERIC_CHOICES = (
      ('1', 'Numeric'),
      ('A', 'Alphabetic'),
  )

  year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
  position_7_char = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ALPHA_NUMERIC_CHOICES)
  position_10 = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=False)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return unicode(self.year)


class Series(models.Model):

  series = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
  model = models.ForeignKey(Model)
  date_added = models.DateField()

  def __unicode__(self):
      name = str(self.model)+" "+str(self.series)
      return name


class CommonVehicle(models.Model):

  year = models.ForeignKey(Year)
  series = models.ForeignKey(Series)
  engine = models.ForeignKey(Engine)
  body_style = models.ForeignKey(BodyStyle)
  transmission = models.ForeignKey(Transmission)
  drive_train = models.ForeignKey(DriveTrain)

  def __unicode__(self):
      name = ''+str(self.year)+" "+str(self.series)
      return name


class Vehicle(models.Model):

  stock_number = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=False)
  vin = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=False)
  common_vehicle = models.ForeignKey(CommonVehicle)
  exterior_colour = models.ForeignKey(ExteriorColour)
  interior_colour = models.ForeignKey(InteriorColour)
  interior_type = models.ForeignKey(InteriorType)
  odometer_unit = models.ForeignKey(OdometerUnit)
  status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
  odometer_reading = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  selling_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  purchase_date = models.DateField()
  sales_description = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.stock_numberodels.ForeignKey(CommonVehicle)
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? Maybe provide your model definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the actual IDs? Try something like `my_vehicle_ref.series.id`.

Also, I hope you know that the `series` attribute right there is really an instance of `Series`, so you could access *any* of it's properties, e.g., `my_vehicle_ref.series.model.model`.

Comment: BTW...I'm accessing these values from a template...not so sure if this is what you meant but vehicle.year.id is supposed to return the year...right?  I'm a bit new to Django so I've yet to grasp it fully.

Comment: Have you gone through the (tutorial)[http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/]? It's a nice intro.

`vehicle.year.id` would return the `id` attribute of that `Year`, which is probably auto-generated and most likely isn't what you want. In the provided model definitions, `Year` doesn't have any attributes that would match what most people traditionally think of as a model year. You may want to add a `model_year = CharField(max_length=6)` attribute, or similar.

Comment: I still haven't gotten it to work...I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: What, exactly, isn't working? Also, have you gone through the tutorial?

Comment: I you need just the ID, `my_vehicle_ref.series_id` also works and avoids querying the series table because it just returns the value of the foreign key column.