# Sorting Records using Foreign Keys

Tags: django, sorting, foreign-keys

From my question at [Get Foreign Key Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362426/get-foreign-key-value), I managed to get the desired output...only one last bit remains.  I want to sort my records by the year, make, then model in that order.  I thought it'd be as simple as `Vehicle.objects.all().order_by('common_vehicle')` but this doesn't sort anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to order by specific fields in the related class. You do this by using the double-underscore format. So, for example:

```
Vehicle.objects.order_by('common_vehicle__year', 'common_vehicle__series__model__model')
```

to sort by the `year` value of the `CommonVehicle` class, then the `model` value of the `Model` class which is related via the `Series` class.

Note that this is a *lot* of joins, and could make your query performance quite slow. It may be fine for your needs, but just a heads-up that this is a potential source of slowness down the line.

Comment: Didn't know about the double underscore.  For now this'll have to do...I'll keep in mind to check the query performance.  Thnx :)